# Size of VARCHAR(MAX) in ROW

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm currently working on a project that will allow one of our clients to sync data from our hosted environment to a client's local database. The problem is that the clients can choose from thousands of columns and create the tables the way they want. In addition to this the size of `VARCHAR` columns isn't known. To handle this I am using `VARCHAR(MAX)` for all text columns.

To determine which columns go to which tables the client will use a tool (that we provide) to map our fields to a table/column of their choosing. We limit the number of fields to 500 per table.

My problem is that when creating a setup for internal testing I'm getting a warning from SQL Server:

> The maximum length of the row exceeds the permissible limit of 8060 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.

In one example table set up for testing there are 247 (of 500) columns with a type of `NUMERIC(23, 10)`, 235 (of 500) with a type of `VARCHAR(MAX)` and 18 (of 500) with a type of `DATETIME`.

The `NUMERIC` and `DATETIME` columns can use a total of 3355 bytes (13 bytes per `NUMERIC` and 8 bytes per `DATETIME`). That just leaves the `VARCHAR(MAX)` columns.

From everything I've been able to find it says that the data in a `VARCHAR(MAX)` column can be up to 2GB and that anything that can't be stored in the row gets moved to another page.

Here is the Microsoft page I have been looking at.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186981(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Even if the actual string is moved off row the row still needs a pointer to the string location and this is stored in row.

Comment: @MartinSmith, that's for the feedback. I hadn't even considered that. After seeing your comment I did some more searching at it appears that the pointer is 24 bytes. However, even considering that it still seems like the max size I can get before getting the warnings is around 7500 bytes. Any idea what the other ~500 bytes is used by?